# OSGI bundle exception caused by a 'uses constraint violation'

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to extend a rule in the eclipse PMD plugin via a plugin fragment. When I try to test my code I get this error which seems to be caused by one of my plugin's dependency projects.

```
!ENTRY net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin 4 0 2015-06-17 09:30:10.972
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin [1086]
  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.0.7.v20150522-1709"; singleton:="true"] because it exports package 'org.apache.log4j' and is also exposed to it from resource org.apache.log4j [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.apache.log4j"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.15.v201012070815"] via the following dependency chain:

  net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.0.7.v20150522-1709"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis)(bundle-version>=1.0.0))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle; osgi.wiring.bundle="de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis"; bundle-version:Version="1.0.0.qualifier"; singleton:="true"
  org.eclipse.xtext.util [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.xtext.util"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.8.3.v201506010551"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.log4j)(version>=1.2.15))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.apache.log4j
  org.apache.log4j [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.apache.log4j"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.2.15.v201012070815"]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Can anyone decode what this error message means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is due to the `Require-Bundle` directive in `net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin` bundle coupled with the `Export-Package` directive for `org.apache.log4j` (this is more or less just a rephrasal of the felix error message).

The required bundle `de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis` imports log4j and at the same time `et.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin` has log4j jars in its classpath (since it exports it, this is what the error message it telling you). This leads to org.apache.log4j package duplication and triggers the error.

Try to remove the `org.apache.log4j` bundle from your runtime in order to let `de.fu_berlin.inf.archnemesis` resolve log4 from `net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin`.

Read also [this post](http://njbartlett.name/2011/09/02/uses-constraints.html) about *Solving OSGi "Uses" Constraint Violations* by Neil Bartlett: I found it very interesting.